# How to get the nested files alone in the IBM COS in nodeJS using listObjects

Tags: node.js, cloud, ibm-cloud

AM trying to access the child contents. For ex: folder B, folder A->B->C. 
`cos.listObjects({ Bucket: "file-ej22", Delimiter:  "B/", Marker: "B/", Prefix: "B/" }` Its listing the entire B values in the response content. But I need only the `folder B`. But its listing the both the folder B and the folder inside the A folder also. Could you tell me how to filter and get  the required folder data alone in IBM cloud in nodejs.

Comment: I'm not following.  Can you express what you want  in using bash globbing?  Do you want A/B/* but not A/B/C/*

Comment: I need to list all the folders and files under a certain folder. could tell me how to make the query in the IBM Cloud storage to retrieve all the files and directory from the particular folder.